# parallel in plyr, modifying a global variable

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to read thousands of file and calculate some statistics. The file are huge (2D maps) and I can not save the whole data into memory. Therefore, I want to read files one by one and calculate some metrics like sum and number of data which can be used after all files are read to calculate mean.

I can do it using plyr::laply and read files,

```
sum<-matrix()
plyr::laply(fileNameList, function(x){
      data <- readFunction(x)  # this part is the most time consuming part which I need the parallel part for. 
      sum <<- sum + data
  }, .parallel = TRUE)
```

My question is how this done in parallel. Does it lock the value of sum for one process and unlock when it is done and unlock it for the next process? I have checked it for some simple example such as:

```
a<-2
plyr::llply(c(1:100000), function(x) return(a<-a+x), .parallel=TRUE)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using the `foreach` package to sum the results from each loop iteration. Here is a toy example:

```
# Package to run for loops in parallel
library(foreach)
# Register a parallel backend
library(doMC)
# Do job in parallel with 2 cores
registerDoMC(2)

# Make 100 random 3x3 matrices and sum the results with .combine = '+'
# %dopar% tells foreach to run this loop in parallel
result <- foreach(i=1:100, .combine = '+') %dopar% {
  matrix(rnorm(9), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
}

result
#          [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] -1.475609   4.358915  2.471485
#[2,] -3.692420  -3.923253 -6.362911
#[3,] -4.628771 -12.974234 -6.032499
```

For your case, based on the code you gave in your example, you can try the following:

```
result <- foreach(i = seq_along(fileNameList), .combine = '+') %dopar% {
  readFunction(fileNameList[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the blocking or unblocking, but you should be safe if you assign the results to indices of a vector.  You can pass indices instead of the list itself to laply.

```
myList<-list(a=sample(1:100,5), b=sample(1:100,5), c=sample(1:100,5))
sumVec<-rep(0,length(myList))
plyr::laply(1:length(myList), 
    function (x){
        sumVec[x]<<-sum(myList[[x]])
    },
    .parallel=TRUE
)
```